# Error doing a post from a dart app to a laravel 4 api using CORS

Tags: http, laravel, laravel-4, dart, cors

I have a REST API developed using Laravel 4. The client is written using Dart Language.

When my Dart app does a GET it all works fine, but when it does a post I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users. Origin http://127.0.0.1:3030 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My Dart function making the request:

```dart
void submitForm(Event e) {
e.preventDefault(); // Don't do the default submit.

request = new HttpRequest();

request.onReadyStateChange.listen(onData); 

// Get Basic Auth credentials
var auth_string = 'admin:admin'; // Default admin login for creating new user accounts
var auth_base64 = window.btoa(auth_string);
var authorization = 'Basic '+auth_base64;

// POST the data to the server.
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users';
request.open('POST', url);
request.withCredentials = true;
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization',authorization);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
print(siftedregistrationAsJsonData());
request.send(siftedregistrationAsJsonData());
}
```

My Laravel 4 before and after filter (as defined in filters.php):

```dart
App::before(function($request)
{
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    $statusCode = 204;

    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => 'http://localhost:3030',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400'
    ];

    return Response::make(null, $statusCode, $headers);
}});

App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3030');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Max-Age','86400');
    return $response;
});
```

And this is the header I get using Chrome Dev Tools:

```
    Request URL:http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:204 No Content
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:3030
     Referer:http://127.0.0.1:3030/Users/salarrahmanian/Dropbox/Projects/phpstorm/sifted/app/dart/web/out/sifted.html
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1530.0 (Dart) Safari/537.36
    Response Headersview source
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3030
    Access-Control-Max-Age:86400
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Connection:close
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Date:Wed, 10 Jul 2013 18:38:42 GMT
    Host:localhost:8000
    X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.14
    Your help and input on this really appreciated.
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think headers are being set, did you check the headers using Firebug or chrome debugging tools??

Comment: I'm not sure, but does it handle it the difference in the address right? You open in browser via the ip and in the headers is the hostname? Could be a difference...

Comment: Added header I get back to original post

Answer (score 0):

You're allowing origin `http://localhost:3030`, but then requesting from `http://127.0.0.1:3030`.

Change:

```
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3030');
```

to

```
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:3030');
```

**Note:** Unfortunately you can't set Allow-Origin to '*' when using Authorization - Just an FYI in case you tried that also.

Comment: Tried your suggestion and I still get same problem :-(